# TextBox filtering according to RadioButton selection

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've a `RadioButtonList` and a `TextBox`. Accordindg to RadioButtonList selection, I want to filtrering textbox.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"  runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
      <asp:ListItem Text="NUMBER" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="TEXT" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server">
```

When I click listitem with value `1`, user can enter number to textbox. value `2`, number + text.
also I want to set the length. Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: I don't want to use Ajax Control Toolkit

Comment: It's not clear what you want or what you've tried. Do you want to filter  that TextBox in javascript according to the selection in the `RadioButtonList`?

Comment: yes, I want to change textbox's filter type in javascript. one option, it will be numeric text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a Javascript function which will get selected value from the `RadioButtonList1` control and compare with value `1` or `2`. If it is `1`, user should be allowed to enter numbers only. This can be enforced from client side key press event of text box, which will check the result of comparison, to allow the pressed key to actually render in the text box.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359127/how-to-find-selected-item-from-radiobutton-list-using-javascript) to see how to get selected value from `RadioButtonList` control using `Javascript`