# RadioButtonList checked with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am trying for a simple validation which consist of a RadioButtonList `rblstPallet`. I tried the below code:

**javascript**

```
var rblstPallet = document.getElementById('rblstPallet');
var counter = 0;
for (var intCount = 0; intCount < rblstPallet.length; intCount++) {
    if (rblstPallet[intCount].checked) {  //this step is not working
        console.log(intCount); //I checked using this step
        counter++;
    }
}
if (counter == 0) {        
    //MSG: please select any item
}
else {
    // Redirect to next page function
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblstPallet" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem>Wood</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Plastic</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The problem is that if I even select one of the Radio Button, then also the `counter` value is remaining same. when I debugged the code, I came to know that the line

> if (rblstPallet[intCount].checked) {

is not even executing nor even showing any errors in console. I am going through this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/204244/JavaScript-RadioButtonList-get-and-set-values). I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9359309/1577396)(not working).

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadioButtoList is converted in radio buttons having id similar to radiobuttonlist id, you need to `iterate` through DOM to find the `matching` elements.

```
function getRadioButtonListSelections(radioButtonListName)
{
     int selectionCount = 0;
     for(i=0;i<document.forms[0].length;i++)
     {
            e=document.forms[0].elements[i];
            if (e.id.indexOf(radioButtonListName) != -1 && e.checked)
                selectionCount++;
     }  
     return selectionCount; 
}       

alert(getRadioButtonListSelections('rblstPallet'));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working... Till now I was unable to understand it, as I am beginner.. :)

Comment: for loop iterates through form elements current we are iterating through form with zero index document.forms[0]. The elements collection give you object of forms elements[i]. indexOf is used to find elements having ids containing rblstPallet

Answer (score 0):

Either use:

```
var rblstPallet = document.getElementById('<%=rblstPallet.ClientID=>');
```

Or

set the client id mode to static:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblstPallet" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ClientIDMode="static">
```

And find and loop through each radio button:

```
var rblstPallet = document.getElementById('rblstPallet');
rblstPallet  = rblstPallet.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
```

Comment: I cant understand the last line.. can you please show a sample..I mean where should I use it in my js code.

Comment: console error --> `object #<nodelist> has no method 'querySelectorAll'`

Comment: Which browser are you using

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(rblstPallet ) before querySelectorAll

Comment: Which means you can't get the rblstPallet. Did you set the clientIdMode to static

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var rblstPallet = document.getElementById('rblstPallet');
```

By

```
var rblstPallet = document.getElementById('<%= rblstPallet.ClientID %>');
```

If you want to validate your radiobuttonlist why don't you use a validator control ?

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPallet" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="rblstPallet" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: I used this.. Its not working.. as I mentioned in my post. :)